# Assigning values to initialized pointers

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

When we declare a pointer, we usually initialize it to a variable (memory mapping) and then assign a value to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i=0;

int cir_shift(int *x,int *y);

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,*temp,*d;

    d=&c;

    scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c); 
    temp=(d+3);
    *temp=c;

    cir_shift(d,temp);
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
}

int cir_shift(int *x,int *y)
{
    *x=*(x+1);
    i++;
    if(i==3)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        x++;
        cir_shift(x,y);
    }
}
```

Here, when I want to print the value of temp (*temp), it keeps crashing. I did initialize 'temp' to a memory address, but still it crashes. And, when I want to print the memory address stored at temp, it prints the value at temp (*temp). What seems to be the problem and what may the solution be? Thank you.

Comment: What's `&c + 3` supposed to be?

Comment: `temp=(d+3);` this will result in undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
 temp=(d+3);
*temp=c;
```

`d + 3` means `3` `int` after where `d` is pointing to. It is an invalid address as you didn't allocate anything there. So then trying to write to `*temp` unleashes the infinite revenge of your implementation.

You should explain what you are trying to achieve with `temp=(d+3);`?

Comment: `d+3` unleashes that revenge even without the next line.

Comment: @chris Until an access is done, `temp = d + 3` is harmless, like `temp = NULL` is. Simply `*temp` is undefined either for reading or writing.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Part of the addition operator (see C11 §6.5.6/8): *If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined* Only `d + 0` and `d + 1` are valid for a single object, since those are treated like an array of one element for this purpose (per /7).

Comment: @chris Even though just `d+3` is UB, it won't actually unleash any revenge on most platforms. Which makes it all the more insidious, waiting for future code or platform change, but still.

Comment: @hyde, True, just pointing it out. The `*temp` is far more likely to cause issues.

Comment: What I wanted to do was that I wanted to point to a specific memory location after the variable a. As you see, the variables, c,b,a will have an ascending memory address(right to left function call). So, the memory location after that will be 3 (4*3) greater than that of c. Hence temp=d+3.
And, if *temp were to cause issues, then why does the program compile without any error? Even more so, if I didn't assign a value to *temp, then the output was getting wrong.